# jQuery getting specific value in page title

Tags: javascript

`(1) Website Name`

`(3) Website Name - 08-08-2013 New York City`

From the examples above, how would I be able to get the value from between the parentheses using jQuery or Javascript?

I understand I would be able to get the title from using the code below

`var current_title = $(document).attr('title');`

But unsure how to pinpoint the actual value between parentheses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you could use:

```
'(3) Website Name - 08-08-2013 New York City'.split(')')[0].substr(1);
// so, with the acquired title:
$(document).attr('title').split(')')[0].substr(1);
```

Alternatively, this `RegExp` replacement would do the same

```
$(document).attr('title').replace(/^(\()(\d+)(\)).*$/,'$2');
```

Comment: What happens if the number is 10?

Comment: The result will be "10" ;).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp according to this guide would you not be skipping the first char?

Comment: @lee - `$(document).attr('title').split(')')[0]` returns `(3` and `.substr(1)` removes the first character so the result is `3`.

Comment: Yes, and it's meant to do that. Check the result of `'(3) Website Name - 08-08-2013 New York City'.split(')')[0]`

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, I never spotted that the first char would be '('

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use a regular expression for this, like so:

```
var num = $( document ).attr( 'title' ).replace( /^.*\((\d+)\).+/, '$1' );
```

This function will return whatever number it finds between two parenthesis. If you know that the number you want is always at the start of the string you can simplify it slightly:

```
var num = $( document ).attr( 'title' ).replace( /^\((\d)\).+/, '$1' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also do it with regex

```
var numInTitle = $(document).attr('title').match(/\d+(?=\))/);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mz3UL/)